# MongoDb Failed _id or unique index constraint

Tags: json, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to post more data in the database. Currently I hold one data:

```
[{"_id":"5f56b28dc05cb9a5b83e4412","check":116756,"url":"http://localhost:3001/url","__v":0}]
```

The DB model is like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const modelSchema = new Schema({
  check: {
          type:Number,
          index: true,
          required:true,
          unique:true
    },

  url: {
        type: String,
        index: true,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    }
});
```

So for each unique check and unique URL a new entry should be valid.
But even if I try completely random entry like:

```
{"check" : 1700, "url" : "http://lonkcalhost:3001/url"}
```

it is still giving the `code 11000` error.

The specific error is:

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.modelurls. Failed _id or
 unique index constraint.
```

I don't understand where I am doing wrong.

Comment: You have _unique_ constraints on three fields: `_id`, `check` and `url`. Make sure all three values are unique for each document you are inserting _or_ updating.

Comment: Even if i remove the `unique` part for both URL and check I still get the same error

Comment: I dont know the exact reason but it is working when I replace check with id. I guess it is azure cosmos db issue as I checked it directly on cosmos db and then implemented locally with postman

Answer (score 0):

So what you need to do is go to your azure portal, then the cosmos db resource, navigate to data explorer and delete the that particular collection...

Make the changes to your schema by removing the unique option and restart your server.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).